# Update a table in SQL Server with User defined

Tags: sql-server

I am updating a table in SQL Server with around 100 different conditions. The following is a list of examples for the updating SQL I am doing.

The problem is that the table `mytable.table1` is a little bit big (has 2 million rows). Those 100 updating queries together takes more than 10 mins.

Is there a way to create a user defined function to update the table with less queries. I don't have index in the table mentioned. Each update query will have to go through the whole table.

I read a bit about user defined functions in SQL Server, didn't find too much about my situation.

--------------------UPDATE 1 -------------------------------

my updating queries is not only updating the column to one single value.

---

```
update  p
set p.column1 = 'abc'
from mytable.table1 p
where p.column2 = 'a' and p.column3 = 'b' 

update  p
set p.column1 = 'edf'
from mytable.table1 p
where p.column2 = 'c' or p.column4 = 'd' 

update  p
set p.column1 = 'wxf'
from mytable.table1 p
where p.column3 = 'd' and p.column5 = 'f' 

update  p
set p.column1 = 'xyz'
from mytable.table1 p
join mytable.table2 c on p.column1 = c.column1
where p.column2 = 'w' and p.column3 = 'a' 

update  p
set p.column1 = 'ere'
from mytable.table1 p
join mytable.table2 c on p.column1 = c.column1
join mytable.table3 r on p.column2 = r.column2
where p.column2 = 'w' and p.column3 = 'b' or p.column4 = 'a'
```

Answer (score 2):

Try something like that:

```
UPDATE
    p
SET
    p.column1 = 'abc'
FROM
    mytable.table1 p
    LEFT JOIN mytable.table2 c ON p.column1 = c.column1
    LEFT JOIN mytable.table3 r ON p.column2 = r.column2
WHERE
    ( ( p.column2 = 'a'
        AND p.column3 = 'b'
      )
      OR ( p.column2 = 'c'
           OR p.column4 = 'd'
         )
      OR ( p.column3 = 'd'
           AND p.column5 = 'f'
         )
      OR ( c.column1 IS NOT NULL
           AND p.column2 = 'w'
           AND p.column3 = 'a'
         )
      OR ( c.column1 IS NOT NULL
           AND r.column2 IS NOT NULL
           AND ( p.column2 = 'w'
                 AND p.column3 = 'b'
                 OR p.column4 = 'a'
               )
         )
    );
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I didn't make my point clear enough. It's not only setting the column1 to 'abc', there are cases, to set p.column1='def'.

Comment: in that case you can do something like: SET p.column1 = CASE WHEN p.column2 = 'a' AND p.column3 = 'b' THEN 'abc' WHEN p.column2 = 'c'
           AND p.column4 = 'd' THEN 'def' ... END

Answer (score 1):

If you are describing a real situation and this is not another College oriented restricted challenge then:

1. You **have** to use indexes in order to improve performance.
2. Functions in MS SQL can save you time on development and/or can make your code more clear, but they are not an index(es) "killer" ;)
3. If your example is a realistic one then of course you can use one update statement as @sidux noted above. But remember, with indexes you statement will completed in a few secs...

I suggest you to use the above statement as well as indexes.